# Mongoid with Parent References is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, parent-child

I'm trying to do [Model Tree Structures with Parent References](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-parent-references/) using Mongoid,
but the **parent is set to null**.

This is my class:

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Category'
end
```

And this is how I create categories:

```
parent = Category.new(name: "Mobile").save!
child1 = Category.new(name: "Android", parent: parent).save!
child2 = Category.new(name: "iOS", parent: parent).save!
```

The result:

```
{ 
    "categories": [
        {
            "_id": "511b84c5cff53e03c6000126",
            "name": "Mobile",
            "parent_id": null,
        },
        {
            "_id": "511b84c5cff53e03c6000128",
            "name": "Android",
            "parent_id": null,
        },
        {
            "_id": "511b84c5cff53e03c6000129",
            "name": "iOS",
            "parent_id": null,
        }
    ]
}
```

The parent is not even stored in the DB:

```
{ "name" : "Mobile",  "_id" : "511b84c5cff53e03c6000126" }
{ "name" : "Android", "_id" : "511b84c5cff53e03c6000128" }
{ "name" : "iOS",     "_id" : "511b84c5cff53e03c6000129" }
```

What am doing wrong?

Thanks!
Roei

Comment: can't see your `has_one` declaration

Comment: @apneadiving where should I use 'has_one'? Thanks!

Comment: @Roei I guess your are missing foreign_key clause try this `foreign_key => :parent_id` ans see if it help

Comment: @Viren I managed to make it work (not foreign key needed), posted my answer. Thanks for your respond!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually it worked when I did the save separately (and not on the same line with the creation).

Before (not works properly):

```
parent = Category.new(name: "Mobile").save!
child1 = Category.new(name: "Android", parent: parent).save!
child2 = Category.new(name: "iOS", parent: parent).save!
```

After (works!):

```
parent = Category.new(name: "Mobile")
child1 = Category.new(name: "Android", parent: parent)
child2 = Category.new(name: "iOS", parent: parent)

parent.save
child1.save
child2.save
```

The result (as expected):

```
{ "name" : "Mobile", "_id" : "511b84c5cff53e03c6000126" }
{ "name" : "Android", "parent_id" : "511b84c5cff53e03c6000126", "_id" : "511b84c5cff53e03c6000128" }
{ "name" : "iOS", "parent_id" : "511b84c5cff53e03c6000126", "_id" : "511b84c5cff53e03c6000129" }
```

Thanks a lot to all responders!

Comment: How do get all parent categories.
Category.where(:parent_id => nil)
is not working.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to declaring a `belongs_to` association you need to declare the opposite `has_many` association, even if it is on the same class.

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String

  has_many :children,
    class_name: 'Category',
    inverse_of: :parent
  belongs_to :parent,
    class_name: 'Category',
    inverse_of: :children
end
```

You can the assign a parent or the children through the associations.

```
parent = Category.create
child1 = Category.create
child2 = Category.create

parent.children << child1
parent.children << child2
```

The children will then store the reference to the parent.

Comment: Are you assigning the parent / childrens through the association?

Comment: @ThomasKlemn I only use 'belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category"' to define the relation. I managed to make it work, posted my answer. Thanks for your respond!